# Error [36, 17, 145] occurred while attempting to drop allocation unit ID ##### belonging to worktable with partition ID #####

Tags: sql-server-2016, tempdb

We regularly get this error on a SQL Server 2016 SP2 instance.

> (Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2) (KB4052908) - 13.0.5026.0 (X64)
> Mar 18 2018 09:11:49   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise
> Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016
> Datacenter 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor))

> Error [36, 17, 145] occurred while attempting to drop allocation unit
> ID ##### belonging to worktable with partition ID #####.

There is not much to find about this error therefore I added extended events to get extra information

I seems to be happening on several SELECT statements from an application that are really fast forward cursors.

In the plan there are a Clustered Index Insert and a clustered index seek on the CWT_PrimaryKey

I was wondering if the worktable in the error message is related to the CWT Cursor Work Table in tempdb and if so why it is happening sometimes ?

I could find this on the Internet seems somewhere related but much older version :

When a query execution plan is cached, the tempdb work tables required by the plan, if any, are often cached.
We had this exact problem when we were on SQL Server 2005 SP2 early builds when there was high tempdb activity + a mistimed job that updates statistics on a relatively large table in the middle of the day.
After talking to Bob Ward at MSFT, it was identified that a resource monitor was trying to free up a cached plan that has a cursor, where it was trying to deallocate a worktable but gets stuck on a latch for an IAM page in tempdb.
The solution that worked for us was to change the schedule for the update stats job + reduced the load on tempdb.
I would suggest you to look at the VirtualFileStats DMV and see the amount of IO you are doing against tempdb when compared to other databases.
For us at the time of this issue, our tempdb IO activity was 90% of the total activity on the box. After few optimizations, we got it down to 50-60%.
I am NOT sure if this really helps you but wanted to share some notes.

If you search for the unit ID belonging to worktable with partition ID it cannot be found anymore so I don’t what it is and if this error is really an issue.

So maybe performance of the tempdb database (IO) or not such an ideal fast forward cursor (plan) but I really want to understand what is happening maybe you can give me a clue.